# Meta_query with relation 'OR' killing server CPU

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query, server-load

```
function get_nb_offres( $typeOffre ) {

    global $type_bien_correspondances;
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'annonces',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR'
        )
    );

    foreach( $type_bien_correspondances[$typeOffre] as $typeBien ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => 'type_de_bien',
                'value' => $typeBien
        );
    }

    $annonces = new WP_Query( $args );
    return $annonces->post_count;
}
```

My global $type_bien_correspondances is here :

```
$type_bien_correspondances = array(
    'Appartement' => array(
        'studios',
        'T1',
        'T2',
        'T3',
        'T4',
        'T5'
    ),
    'Immeuble' => array(
        'immeuble'
    ),
    'Programme neuf' => array(
        'programme neuf'
    ),
    'Maison, Villa' => array(
        'maison',
        'villa',
        utf8_encode( 'propriété' )
    ),
    'Fond de commerce' => array(
        'fond de commerce'
    ),
    'Terrain' => array(
        'terrain'
    )
);
```

And finally my call to the get_nb_offres() function is here :

```
// Within a function
return get_nb_offres( 'Appartement' );
```

My problem is when running this code my server CPU goes crazy and I can't do anything but restart it. Commenting the 'relation' line make the code work but it's not what I'm expecting.

I can still muddle through this problem running several WP_Query but I would prefer to understand where the bug comes from.

EDIT

Not really an answer but several clues to optimize my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Afaik*, there's no `relation` key for [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). Use `compare` instead and maybe also specify a `type` to speed things up with skipping types that are out of scope.

**EDIT**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
            // Used to set two meta keys IN RELATION TO EACH OTHER
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'color',
            'value' => 'blue',
                    // Used to FILTER OUT/IN/LIKE THE VALUE NAME
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value' => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
  );
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: There's an example in the codex with the relation key for meta_query. Check the very last example here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: You're using it completely wrong. First: That's only for two `meta_query` arrays that you want to set in `relation` to _each other_. Second: That should be placed _outside_ the array - as seen in the codex. See Edit _with the codex example_.

Comment: Thanks for the information but... First: it's not explicitly written its limited to two meta_query arrays. Second: that's exactly what I did - 'relation' is a key of 'meta_query' in my example too. I'm just populating meta_keys and meta_values dynamicaly later in the script.

Comment: Ah, ok. Overseen the `[]`. And yes. `compare` is to compare values inside the matching keys and `relation` is the relation the keys should've to each other. Please give that a try. Btw: You should try to intercept the query on `posts_clauses` filter. I guess your dataset + query args is just too big for your server. You should maybe update your Q with what your expected output is.

Comment: Large Meta queries are indeed performance killers. There's some ideas to reduce this, but basically if you're asking for a lot of SQL work, it's gonna take a lot of CPU to do it. There is no current fix, short of a custom query.

Comment: @Otto Thank for jumping in. Yea, sadly every meta query does a separate `JOIN`, if I'm right. Don't really understand why not doing the `JOIN` once and then simply calling in the columns you need.

Comment: I made a ticket on this (for tax_query) a while back. It's a slightly complex problem to make a smarter query that works for all cases: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18105

Comment: @Otto Sad that there was no progress so this could be moved into 3.4. I just had to deal with something like this yesterday. Gladly I didn't had to modify the query itself as its result wasn't that large, but seeing a slight chance that the `meta/tax_query` behavior changes, feels good.